# 32.768 kHz crystal for RTC, should the case be soldered to GND?

Tags: crystal, rtc

I've seen this on a few boards, but I don't know if it's the right thing to do. Should the case be soldered to GND?

It is the common cylindrical [package](http://uk.farnell.com/ael-crystals/x32k768l009/crystal-32-768000khz/dp/9509690):

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/158383/why-are-32-786khz-crystal-cans-soldered-to-pcb  or http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42818/is-case-grounding-compulsory-in-typical-32-768khz-crystal-for-real-time-clock

Comment: A good question that's already been asked.

Answer (score 0):

As for i know  to EMI consideration the metal body is ground. Grounding the oscillator may reduce emissions.  I have crossed this point for EMI consideration "http://www.intel.com/design/pentiumii/applnots/24333402.pdf" for heatsink. It may applicable for Oscillator also.